# HTML - vertical align responsive images

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, styles

I'm doing a template for an email with pure HTML and css

this is my actual result

[image: actual result horizontal]

i need to have 3 images for good and 3 images for no good

but now i need to do something like this

[image: expected result]

My question is how can i do the structure for a responsive container with the expected result.

this is some of my actal code

```css
.column {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        .col-50 {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-50 text-center">
       <img width="250" height="250" src="base64code" alt=\"good\">
       <img width="250" height="250" src="base64code" alt="good">
      </div>
     <div class="col-50 text-center">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="base64code" alt=\"good\">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="base64code" alt="good">
     </div>
    </div>
```

"

But it doesn´t work, i dont know what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned this is going to be for an HTML email, my recommendation would be to go with a less modern style of coding and build out the email with tables. The reason being, emails have never had great html and css support, and still suffer from simple design problems that you would never have with a modern website.

Depending on what email clients you want to support, you could run into the following kinds of problems:

- CSS in the head tag will be ignored
- link rel="stylesheet"... will be stripped from the email (won't be used)
- div tags will be 100% width even if you try to style them otherwise
- Margins styles are ignored (I always use padding instead for emails)

There are a ton of rules about which email clients will allow different styles, and your best bet is always to inline your styles directly on the html tags. You can find a really handy guide to what is and isn't allowed here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

For your example above, I would turn this into a table as follows:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" align="center">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="good" style="display: block;">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="good" style="display: block;">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="good" style="display: block;">
    </td>
    <td width="50%" align="center">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="good" style="display: block;">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="good" style="display: block;">
      <img width="250" height="250" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="good" style="display: block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can then add padding to the images to allow for vertical space between them (margins aren't great in emails).

If you need to change the width on the images for responsive purposes, you can use a media query in the head. Most mobile email clients will read media queries in an email head properly, and will use a percentage width on the image properly (% of container instead of percentage of image dimensions), so for mobile you can give the images a % width to better use the space.

```
@media (max-width: 599px){ //Assuming desktop is 600px+
    img{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Sadly, because of inline styles, this requires the use of !important tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of layout to create the above page.

One possible solution to use CSS Grid system:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Vertical Align</title>
        <style>
            .grid-container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: auto auto;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                background-color: #2196F3;
                padding: 10px;
            }

            .grid-container > div {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 30px;
                margin: 25px 50px;
                padding: 50px 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div>Good 1</div>
            <div>No Good 1</div>
            <div>Good 2</div>  
            <div>No Good 2</div>
            <div>Good 3</div>
            <div>No Good 3</div>
            <div>Good ...</div>
            <div>No Good ...</div>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
img{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row m-auto">
  <div class="col-xs">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
  </div>
</div>
```